# Jenkins UCM ClearCase plugin fails due to rights

Tags: hudson, jenkins, clearcase, hudson-plugins, clearcase-ucm

I am using Jenkins with the source control plugin name `UCM ClearCase`.
It tries to create a view and fails with the error:

```
[onlysourcecode] $ cleartool mkview -snapshot -stream ROLE_Test_Project_DevSG@\Vobname -tag SYSTEM_master_Test_ROLE_001_hudson view
Selected Server Storage Location "Views".
cleartool: Error: unable to set access control list for \\server\viewstor\NT+AUTHORITY\SYSTEM\view.1.vws: Access is denied.
cleartool: Error: protection on \\server\viewstor\NT+AUTHORITY\SYSTEM\view.1.vws is out-of-synch with identity.sd and groups.sd
cleartool: Error: Failed to set identity on view: Permission denied
cleartool: Error: unable to set access control list for \\server\viewstor\NT+AUTHORITY\SYSTEM\view.1.vws: Access is denied.
cleartool: Error: \\server\viewstor\NT+AUTHORITY\SYSTEM\view.1.vws: Permission denied
cleartool: Error: Unable to create view "\\server\viewstor\NT+AUTHORITY\SYSTEM\view.1.vws".
FATAL: UCM ClearCase failed. exit code=1
```

Which basically means it does not have permissions to create a view. Now my questions:

1. Any ideas on what exactly is the problem here?
2. What ID is Jenkins using internally. Meaning I have a user ID on the DOMAIN controller where I log in to the machine and run Jenkins. If Jenkins uses that, then why this error as I can create views.
3. If not, then what ID does it use and how do I get Jenkins to use my domain ID, or else maybe get the internal ID to be a part of the ClearCase AD group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is run on a Windows box as a service.  Thus it is not run as a domain user.

It appears that jenkins is trying to create a view storage (.vws) in the default location, based on the clearcase configuration on the system.

Perhaps you should choose the `Advanced...` option in `UCM Clearcase` and explicitly specify the location for your view storage.  There are

- Windows view storage directory
- Additional mkview arguments

I run jenkins on a linux box where I have specified an explicit location for the .vws file in `Additional mkview arguments`.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Raghuram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254643/raghuram)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8399222/6309), using the system account (`NT+AUTHORITY`) is tricky, because even if you specify a local view storage,:

- that account won't have a `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` associated with its profile
- even if it did, it wouldn't be part of the group referenced by `CLEARCASE_PRIMATY_GROUP`

That means it won't be able to access the *vob* storage of the Vob it will need to access within the view.

Anyway, at the very least you should try and [configure Slave Service to Run as Domain User](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-ConfigureSlaveServicetoRunasDomainUser%28WindowsServer2008R2x64%29).

Comment: Thanks.. I configured the service to ` Log On as ` and it worked.

Comment: @PulakAgrawal: the only downfall is that, in big corporations, your password will change every x months. Having a job defined that way is a great way to get your account locked one day. If you haven't that limitation however, that is a good solution.

Comment: I already realized that the hard way :( (yes, I am in a big corporation) so this was bound to happen but I have a special ID whose password does not expire (for build magmt), so I am safe using that now. Thanks